# Cannot update because of webfilter set in the router

Tags: updates

We use iBoss web-filter. When ever I try to install a program or update the system it fails.  I believe the problem is our web-filter I have tried to list it in the allow websites (sites that are safe)  I should be able to list by ubuntu.com and everything on the ubuntu site would be considered safe. I also tried security.ubuntu.com with no better results.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the failure message? Why do you think your web-filter is the culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file inside Ubuntu with a list of repository locations from where it gets the updates. You have to copy the list of web sites from there into your iBoss web-filter's allow list.

**First,** make a temporary copy of the file we will open, in case we mess it up. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.temp
```

You will be asked to enter your password. The cursor won't move when you enter the password and it will look like nothing happened. This is normal. Type the password and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Second,** now open the list in an editor so that you can copy the web sites. In the terminal enter the code

```
sudo -i gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.temp
```

You will see lots of lines that look like:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
```

**Note 1**, the web site name is the same in the above example. You only need to copy it once.

**Note 2.** You have to copy only the `http://archive.ubuntu.com` part and ignore the rest.

Paste all the different web sites in the list and one by one into your iBoss web-filter configuration page and save the changes.

**Third,** exit the gedit program. Do not save the temp file if it asks. Optionally delete the temp file by the following command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.temp
```

Hope this helps